# Как можно избавится от if в следующей задачке

Tags: javascript, шаблоны-проектирования, typescript

В общем есть какой то набор одинаковых методов которые должны быть вызваны в определенном порядке, и когда найден результат завершить выполнение

```
    class Test{

  getProductByA(){
    return 0;
  }
  getProductByB(){
    return 1;
  }
  getProductByC(){
    return 3;
  }
  getProductByD(){
    return 0;
  }

  getProduct(){
    let methods = ['A','B','C','D'];
    let product = null;

    for(let method of methods){
     if(product = this['getProductBy'+method]()){        
         break;
       }
    }    
    return product;
  }


}

let test = new Test();

console.log('test begin');
console.log(test.getProduct());
console.log('test end');
```

Один из вариантов
https://codepen.io/korolariya/pen/RZzOQw?editors=1111

Второй вариант https://codepen.io/korolariya/pen/PKrvKK?editors=0011

Во втором можно декоратором вставлять одинаковый код, менее гибкий чем первый конечно но все же

Хочу узнать как ещё можно получше решать подобную задачу.

Comment: `if(0)` эквивалентно `if(false)`

Comment: @Grundy ну да, это нужно чтобы смоделировать ситуацию когда метод ничего не вернул